# Plone site will not load after adding package

Tags: plone

In our company we have a plone site to house quality documentation, based on Plone 4.1.4. We have a copy of this site for test purposes.

In this copy I want to make a package, called ‘company.contents’, to house dexterity content. I followed this steps to do this:

first I created the skeleton for the package using ZopeSkel (2.21.2):
zopeskel plone company.contents

Next I changed setup.py and configure.zcml (I followed instructions in the Dexterity Developer Manual)

Then I changed buildout.cfg: (adding the package in the eggs, develop, zcml and sources parts)

```
…


eggs =  
PIL  
Products.CMFPlone  
plone.app.iterate  
Products.CMFEditions  
Products.CMFDiffTool  
plone.app.openid  
Products.CMFPlacefulWorkflow  
plone.app.dexterity  
collective.wtf  
plone.app.versioningbehavior  
collective.cmfeditionsdexteritycompat  
collective.dexteritydiff  
Products.PermissionComprehensible  
plone.app.workflowmanager  
plone.app.stagingbehavior  
webcouturier.dropdownmenu  
Products.TinyMCE  
Products.kupu  
collective.uploadify  
company.contents  
company.addsharing

develop =  
c:\plone41\src\company.addsharing  
c:\plone41\src\company.contents

zcml =  
company.addsharing  
company.contents

…

[sources]  
company.addsharing= fs company.addsharing  
company.contents= fs company.contents

…
```

The package is referenced in the instance-script.py

However, the problem is that the site will not load with this package. If I remove the package references out of buildout.cfg, the site works properly.

Anybody an idea what’s going wrong?

Comment: Run the instance in foreground mode, `bin/instance fg`, to see why the process doesn't work.

Comment: Also, you've got to let us know what you mean by "the site will not load." That could be anything from "Plone isn't starting" to page errors.

Comment: Also see http://plone.org/documentation/kb/diagnosing-third-party-product-installation-problems